# org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 21

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

I have yarn cluster with spark(1.6.1), hdfs and hive(2.1). My workflows worked fine for few months till this day (without any changes in code / on environments). I started to get errors like this:

```
org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 21
Serialization trace:
outputFileFormatClass (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc)
aliasToPartnInfo (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
invertedWorkGraph (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.SparkWork)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:119)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:656)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$ClassSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:238)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$ClassSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:226)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:745)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:113)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:776)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:139)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:17)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:776)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:131)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:17)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient$JobStatusJob.call(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:318)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:366)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Using hive i can do simple selects, but every other operation which needs spark ends with `Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 3 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask (state=08S01,code=3)` in console, and error above in yarn logs.
Now my every hive database is paralyzed (i have few). I was trying to solve this problem whole day, but couldnt do antything (hive restart, yarn node's restarts, changing yarn master).

What do you think causes the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

After restarting hive-server2 for small period of time instead of getting error: `org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 26`  i got error: `org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.RCFileOutputFormat`. With second form it was obvious, that spark executed on node's didn't have some jars on classpath. I don't know the reason, why spark in one moment was unable to load these jars, but after copying them manually to his lib folder on every node and restarting node everything went back to normal.

Comment: Open source, bro. I feel your pain.